# HTML5 Canvas/CSS scaling

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

So I have a web app that lets you draw things like rectangles and shapes. It draws them based on the idea that the first coord is (x1,y1) and the second is (x2,y2). When drawing on a canvas at 100% zoom, everything works as expected. But when I zoom (via CSS) to, say, 80%, the app gets the coords of the mouse position as actual screen pixels from the (0,0) canvas point. It draws them on the scaled canvas with these points, but scaled to the ratio. This makes all the rectangles draw at the wrong coords.

This is confusing to explain, so here's a quick video of me drawing a rectangle on a canvas scaled to 80%. 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15582820/problem.swf
You can see why this doesn't work. Basically there has to be a formula so it can take the scaled coords and multiply them by some number based on the scale (0-100%) to get what the actual screen coords would be at that zoom.

Any help greatly appreciated. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it:

```
zoom = [between 0-100...];
x1 = 100/zoom
```

Sounds simple but this is all it takes.